# passing new lines in command line argument?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, command-line-arguments

I loaded up a small console app that simply reads and prints the first command line argument passed to the program to the console.

I want to pass a newline to the argument I tried this:

```
prog.exe \n  --> outputs \n
prog.exe "sfs \n sfff" --> outputs sfs \n sfff
prog.exe "ff \\n ff" --> outputs ff \\n ff
prog .exe "ff \\\\n ff" --> outputs ff \\\\n ff
```

Is there some other escaping I'm suppose to use?  Or is there some function I have to call on args[0] to process escaped characters before outputting it to the console?

To clarify, I'm trying to pass a string to my program that has newlines in it.  The outputting to console was being used as a test.  I could have just as easily inserted a debug break line and inspect the contents of the variable.

Comment: So you want to call your `prog.exe` from the command line (`cmd`) or from another application?

Comment: @BigYellowCactus Basically, I am receiving several lines of data into memory from another app, and after I receive enough of them I want the app that is doing the receiving to call another program by passing the lines in a command line argument.  I don't want to have a flatfile intermediate step.  It's important to maintain the new lines, based on what people have said I suppose I should use some sort of delimiter for newline and do a replace operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the strings you get from the command line are not compiled.  When you have string literals in your code they are compiled and this is when escape characters are processed and converted into newlines etc.  You will probably have to do something like replacing all instances of "\n" in your input string with a newline character.

**Edit:**

From [here](https://markyourfootsteps.wordpress.com/tag/codedom/) (with minor modifications), this will compile your string using the CSharp compiler thus replacing the escape sequences with the appropriate characters:

```
    public static string ParseString(string input)
    {
        var provider = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider();
        var parameters = new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters()
        {
            GenerateExecutable = false,
            GenerateInMemory = true,
        };

        var code = @"
        public class TmpClass
        {
            public static string GetValue()
            {
                return """ + input + @""";
            }
        }";

        var compileResult = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);

        if (compileResult.Errors.HasErrors)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(compileResult.Errors.Cast<System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerError>().First(e => !e.IsWarning).ErrorText);
        }

        var asmb = compileResult.CompiledAssembly;
        var method = asmb.GetType("TmpClass").GetMethod("GetValue");

        return method.Invoke(null, null) as string;
    }
```

Comment: OK, accepting this as solution.  Though, I ended up not using newlines anyways and going with a different approach that didn't use command line arguments so I didn't actually test this answer... heh

Comment: @user17753 That's ok.  I saw a number of different versions of this same question, and the answer I found is better than the rest so the question is still useful.

Answer (score 2):

Passing line breaks in command line arguments works as expected, actually. Quick test in PowerShell:

```
PS> ./echoargs "a`nb" b c
arg 1: a
b
arg 2: b
arg 3: c
```

Now, if what you're trying is to do the same thing in `cmd` that could prove difficult (and is not really obvious from your question – `Process.Start` would work, though).

Comment: I think you misunderstand.  I think he is literally passing "\n".

Comment: Yes, and they should not do that. But without the question actually detailing *what* they do and *how* we cannot really help them. I suspect they try passing `\n` from within `cmd` but neither the question nor the tags hint at that.

Comment: He actually does specify this point: "Is there some other escaping I'm suppose to use?"  It's pretty clear he's expecting the '\' to convert the 'n' into a newline.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this is useful information.  Not exactly where I was going with this, though.  I edited my question for some clarity.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass `prog .exe "ff \\\\n ff"`

you can replace them from inside your code `var s = arg[0[.Replace("\" ,@"\\");` like this

Answer (score 0):

From the windows command line, this is impossible. For security, C# parses user input from the command line as entirely literal. There are no escape characters that will automatically create a new line, unless you write code to go through the string and replace `\n` with the actual newline character.

If you type in `\n` into the command line, C# will parse that as `\\n`.

Comment: This is wrong. First, it is totally possible to pass an argument to a windows command line application that contains a newline from within the command line (`cmd.exe`). Second, C# doesn't interpret anything. It's a language. And also not an interpreted one.

Comment: You can add a newline character using the escape character `^` in cmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

For python, you can quote-enclose an actual newline. Example:

```
# test.py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('name', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.name)
print([args.name])
```

Calling with newlines as arguments:

```
$ python test.py "hello
world"
```

Outputs:

```
hello
world
['hello\nworld']
```